# Java client for Prometheus APIs

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

Is there any java client for Prometheus, by using which I can execute queries like the below one?

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=up&start=2019-07-01T20:10:30.781Z&end=2019-07-01T20:11:00.781Z&step=15s'
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/anhdat/prometheus4j

Comment: This one would be better: https://github.com/mckang/promql_java_client